# How i can use session in AppServiceProvider without using view composer?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass data (session value ) to my controller using the boot method in AppServiceProvider but it didn't work and when I search I found a solution by using view composer but I looking for a better way to do this without using view composer.

I use `config::set(key,value)` to able to share my value to controller

Comment: Welcome to SO ... are you trying to get data for just one controller? you can access the session in the controller, or you can use a controller middleware to get this data from the session

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify session data in a ServiceProvider. The `StartSession` middleware handles setting up the session in Laravel which is not executed until after all the ServiceProviders have been booted.

Also, the `config` helper doesn't effect session data, it updates config values like those that are in your `config` directory.

If you are trying to update session data, use `session::set(key, value)` instead.